# JFrog Artifactory upload tar via Jenkins failes with 404

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

Since a few days we got an error on a Jenkins Pipeline when we want to upload a tar archive via spec to the Artifactory.
All the Maven builds with goal `deploy` works well and the artifacts gets deployed.
I checked the docs, logs and Stackoverflow.
At the moment I have no further ideas except asking here.

This is the error message of the console output from the Jenkins Pipeline:

```
[...]
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] newBuildInfo
[Pipeline] artifactoryUpload
Executing command: /bin/sh -c git log --pretty=format:%s -1
[consumer_0] Deploying artifact: http://artifactory.name.de/artifactory/snapshots/dir/app-name/release-bundles/1.62.0/app-name-release-bundle-1.62.0.tar.gz
Failed to upload file
[consumer_0] An exception occurred during execution:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: JFrog service failed. Received 404: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>

    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.spec.SpecDeploymentConsumer.consumerRun(SpecDeploymentConsumer.java:44)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.producerConsumer.ConsumerRunnableBase.run(ConsumerRunnableBase.java:11)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: JFrog service failed. Received 404: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>

    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.JFrogService.throwException(JFrogService.java:49)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.artifactory.services.Upload.handleUnsuccessfulResponse(Upload.java:59)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.JFrogService.execute(JFrogService.java:121)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.artifactory.services.Upload.execute(Upload.java:77)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.artifactory.ArtifactoryManager.upload(ArtifactoryManager.java:262)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.artifactory.ArtifactoryManager.upload(ArtifactoryManager.java:257)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.spec.SpecDeploymentConsumer.consumerRun(SpecDeploymentConsumer.java:39)
    ... 2 more
[...]
```

That's the relevant part of the pipeline with the upload spec:

```
def artifactoryServer = Artifactory.server 'art1'
[...]
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('Transfer release bundle to artifactory.') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parentArtifactId = parentPom.artifactId
                    def repository = "snapshots"
                    if(params.branchName == "master") {
                        repository = "releases";
                    }
                        
                    def uploadReleaseArchiveSpec = """{
                        "files": [ 
                            {
                                 "pattern": "release-bundle-${releaseBundleVersion}.tar.gz",
                                 "target": "${repository}/path/to/file/${parentArtifactId}/release-bundles/${parentPom.version}/"
                            }
                        ]                                                 
                    }"""
                        artifactoryServer.upload spec: uploadReleaseArchiveSpec, failNoOp: true
                }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

In the `router-request.log` I found this:

```
{
    "ClientAddr": "127.0.0.1:56828",
    "DownstreamContentSize": 95,
    "DownstreamStatus": 404,
    "Duration": 2531738,
    "RequestMethod": "GET",
    "RequestPath": "/access/api/v1/users/jffe@000?expand=groups",
    "ServiceAddr": "localhost:8040",
    "StartUTC": "2022-09-08T09:39:50.224317922Z",
    "level": "info",
    "msg": "",
    "request_Uber-Trace-Id": "745779c57b007818:30fa1347695348a7:062656bb9a6ef6c9:0",
    "request_User-Agent": "JFrog Access Java Client/7.43.6 74306900  Artifactory/7.38.10 73810900",
    "time": "2022-09-08T11:39:50+02:00"
}
```

There is also an error message in the catalina log from Tomcat of Artifactory:

```
08-Sep-2022 13:52:42.392 SEVERE [http-nio-127.0.0.1-8091-Acceptor] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Acceptor.run Socket accept failed
        java.io.IOException: Duplicate accept detected. This is a known OS bug. Please consider reporting that you are affected: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1924298
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.serverSocketAccept(NioEndpoint.java:548)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.serverSocketAccept(NioEndpoint.java:78)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Acceptor.run(Acceptor.java:129)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

But we are using RedHat Enterprise Linux and not Ubuntu. Otherwise there is an error.
Our environment:

```
Jenkins 2.346.3
Artifactory OSS 7.38.10
Jenkins Artifactory Plug-in 3.17.0 (and 3.16.2 former attempts)
RedHat Enterprise Linux 8.6
```

Has anybody an idea? Did I overseen something in the logs above? Where else should I look?

I saw also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539510/jfrog-artifactory-jenkins-plugins-upload-fails?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C113.5523). Unfortunately without answer.

### UPDATE - 2022-09-13

I found the issue:
The upload works with a directly in the Jenkins Job (via the corresponding text area) inserted Pipeline script and it doesn't work with the same Pipeline script requested from a Git repository.
Now, it would be interesting to know why the second approach fails.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using your own private Jfrog? In that case, does the Jenkins machine have access to your JFrog? Can you ssh into your Jenkins machine and upload a random artifact using curl?

This may not be the best answer, but when dealing with Jfrog, I always simply use curl within the Jenkins pipeline to upload artifacts:

```
curl -u <user>:<password> -X PUT "<jfrog_url>/path/to/upload/artifact.zip" -T "path\on\jenkins\artifact.zip"
```

Comment: Yes, it's an on-premise JFrog on our server. Jenkins is installed on the same machine. Also a Maven Jenkins job can deploy to the artifactory without problems. Nevertheless, I will try your approach.

Comment: Unfortunately, I also got a 404 error with curl with this archive. Is something to consider regarding the path or the size of the file? To deploy a file via UI you can set a maximum size limit. Is there something corresponding for curl or the API?

Comment: If it was a problem with the size limit, I don't think it will be giving a 404 error. I'm not entirely sure why you wouldn't be able to access jfrog that is running in the same machine using curl. See if there is something you missed: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API

Comment: Ok. After looking at the API doc and if I understand it right, the curl call does not work because it requires Artifactory Pro (I added to my first post that we use Artifactory OSS). But that shouldn't be the case regarding the Jenkins Artifactory Plugin. We already deployt tar.gz archives via this plugin before.

Comment: I think I found the issue: it works with a directly in the Jenkins Job inserted Pipeline script and it doesn't work with the same Pipeline script requested from a Git repository (I added this to my first post).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem is Jenkins injects GIT_ environment variables when checking out Pipeline from SCM.

I worked around the problem by resetting GIT_ environment variables.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label("some-agent")
    }

    environment {
        GIT_BRANCH = ""
        GIT_COMMIT = ""
        GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT = ""
        GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT = ""
        GIT_URL = ""
    }

    stages {
        stage("Push to Artifactory") {
            steps {
                rtUpload(
                        serverId: "your-artifactory-instance-id",
                        "buildName": "Your-Build-Name",
                        "failNoOp": true,
                        spec: """
                        {
                            "files": [
                                    {
                                        "pattern": "target/app.jar",
                                        "target": "libs-release-local/some/path/in/artifactory/app.jar"
                                    }
                            ]
                        }
                        """.stripIndent()
                )
                rtPublishBuildInfo(
                        serverId: "your-artifactory-instance-id",
                        "buildName": "Your-Build-Name"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```